# MSVS/C++: fastest always-false condition that won't be optimized away?

Tags: c++, function, performance, visual-c++

I have this code:

```
if (false)
{
    ...code... 
}
```

that the compiler is optimizing away in release builds. I realize it's being removed because it'll never be reached, but I want the code inside to be present in release builds (for reasons).

A simple solution is to make the condition dependent on a function that the compiler won't evaluate. Ex:

```
if (cos(0.5) == 1)
{
    ...code...
}
```

This is not optimized away because the compiler won't evaluate cos(x).

However, I'd like this always-false condition to take as little time as possible to execute because the never-executed code block sits in a larger piece of code whose performance is critical. I know cos(x) is a fast function to evaluate, but are there faster functions I could use in its place (functions which will never be optimized away)? I'm trying to expend as few CPU cycles as possible on this test.

Or more specifically, how can I write a function that will always return false, that the compiler can't evaluate, that will expend fewer CPU cycles than cos(x)? Naive attempts like:

```
bool alwaysFalse(){return false;}

bool alwaysFalse(){return 1 == 2;}

bool alwaysFalse(){return (1-2) == 3;}
```

don't work because the compiler is smart enough to figure them out and optimize my code away.

Comment: No C++ code is present in builds,  there is only machine code in the binaries . Are you saying you want the binaries to contain a bunch of useless machine code at certain points?

Comment: ASM is still code, and that's what I'm referring to, yes.

Comment: Maybe you could surround the `alwaysFalse()` function with [`#pragma optimize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/optimize) pair?

Comment: Please state *why* you want the assembled instructions still present in the release build.

You are always going to face compilers successively resolving more expressions at compile time, so you really have to ask yourself why you don't want that to happen.

Comment: @heapunderrun hey, that worked! And while couched in that pragma, alwaysFalse simply returns false so it can't get much simpler than that.

Comment: `__declspec(noinline)`?

Comment: @Ext3h the OP said `for reasons`; why are you questioning his reasons?

Comment: @VladFeinstein because I suspect that OP tries to depend on specific side effects of not eliminating the dead code, likely something around the line of preventing memory access reordering. For which the requested solution is the wrong tool for the job, as it formally doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the condition variable as volatile?

```cpp
volatile bool condition = false;
if (condition)
{
}
```

Comment: Nope, that still gets optimized away (well, the condition isn't optimized away due to the required volatile read, but the compiler knows it will never be true and removes everything within the interior code block)

Comment: Really? with volatile:  https://godbolt.org/z/f5xP3snaT  Without: https://godbolt.org/z/f5xP3snaT   If the condition 'can be true', then the interior code block cannot by definition be optimised away.

Comment: @robthebloke volatile automatics are a bit of a contentious issue. The compiler vendor, which is in control of the execution environment, argues that there is no possible way that the memory of the automatic could be changed, since nothing else knows where it is .   So they can still assume it will evaluate to the last known value.   OP probably would not see the same if it were a variable with external linkage

Comment: Here's my result in MSVS 2019: https://i.imgur.com/TTPQ8fP.png

Perhaps some quirk of my project is causing this, which would explain why it's not optimized away in your godbolt example...but when using the solution suggested by @heapunderrun above, I don't have the problem.

Comment: @robthebloke the OP is asking about MSVC and you gave **clang** asm output. See no `printf` in MSVC with `volatile`: https://godbolt.org/z/nnnTbz3E1

Comment: @phuclv just move `volatile bool condition = false;` out of main

Comment: @VladFeinstein it's not my answer so why tag me? And if you move the declaration out of `main` then it's not automatic volatile anymore but a volatile at file scope which is completely different

Comment: @phuclv I tagged you because of your statement "See no printf in MSVC with volatile". If you move that declaration out of `main()`, you'd see that `printf` on your godbolt page.

Comment: @VladFeinstein It's just what robthebloke wrote in godbolt and not mine. He wrote it inside main. And as I said, moving it out changes the scope and is completely different

Answer (score -1):

You can set an environment variable and base your test on that variable.

The compiler cannot know the status of the environment variable at compile time so your code will not optimized by the compiler.

I am not a C++ programmer, but the pseudo code should be something like

```
boolean myVar = ENV.myVar; // Where ENV.myVar is the value of an ENV
                           // variable of name myVar evaluated to false
...

if (myVar) {
   ... code ...
}
```

Otherwise, you can create a variable and a setter for that variable never called on your code so you can test for `null` value of that variable. The compiler should not optimize this part because it can't be sure that nobody else will set this variable at runtime.